# Http content loaded in https connection

Tags: javascript, php, image, ssl

My Webapp is running with a https connection / ssl certificate. I need to show pictures to the user. I get the links to the picture by an API request and link them afterwards. Sadly, the pictures address is http, so the browser shows that there are unsecure parts on the site, which mustn't be...

I could download the pictures and link to the proper picture afterwards, but I think this might be a little timeconsuming and not the best way to handle this.

Does somebody know a better solution for this? I'm using php, jquery and javascript.

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to give an answer. Which API? Can't you change `http://` to `https://`, and why not? Are the images on an external resource?

Comment: Amazon MWS ListMatchingProducts

Comment: if I change http:// to https:// it doesn't show any pictures at all. The images are stored on amazon's server

Comment: If the images are external, and you cannot get a secure link, then you have to download them in the background with PHP, and provide a secure link to them on you server. Better still: Make a script that will stream the images as if it is local, and on a secure link. I cannot give an example because I know nothing about Amazon MWS ListMatchingProducts.

Comment: Thought about the script option, too. What will be faster? Downloading or stream? Pictures size is only few kb...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to write a proxy on your server and display all the images through it. Basically your URLs should be like:

```
$url = 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51MU5VilKpL._SL75_.jpg';
$url = urlencode($url);

echo '<img src="/proxy.php?from=' . $url . '">';
```

and the proxy.php:

```
$cache = '/path/to/cache';
$url = $_GET['from'];

$hash = md5($url);
$file = $cache . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $hash;
if (!file_exists($file)) {
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    file_put_contents($file, $data);
}

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

readfile($file);
```

Comment: Becareful when doing things this way as it could be used to do script injections. There is no validation on the source of the images, so potentially it could be used to proxy anything on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've got a streaming example for you. You need to adapt it to your needs, of course.

Suppose you make a php file on your server named `mws.php` with this content:

```
if (isset($_GET['image']))
{
   header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
   header('Content-transfer-encoding: binary');
   echo file_get_contents($_GET['image']);
}
```

Look for any image on the web, for instance:

```
http://freebigpictures.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/mountain-stream.jpg
```

now you can show that image, as if it was located on your own secure server with this url:

```
https://<your server>/mws.php?image=http://freebigpictures.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/mountain-stream.jpg
```

It would of course be better to store the image locally if you need it more than once, and you have to include the correct code to get it from Amazon MWS ListMatchingProducts, but this is the basic idea.

Please don't forget to secure your script against abuse.